# What is the best way to show an overview of advanced filters

Tags: filter, info-visualisation, best-practice

We have both quick and advanced filters in our application.
The advanced filters allow users to create nested filters/conditions (up to 3):
[image]
What is the best way to show an overview/summary for the applied advanced filters? are there any special guidelines?

Comment: Is the user saving this particular configuration for later, and the summary will help them retrieve it?

Comment: This filter is used to filter a table or other view types. The users expect to see a compact version of the applied filters on top of the table. What is the overall filters that are currently applied without opening this dialog to edit the filters